# ploting filled polygons in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polygon

I have two matrices `Tri` and `V` for faces (Nx3) and vertices (Mx3) of polygons that I want to plot. Is there any matplotlib (or any alternative) way to do that? Something similar to Matlab command

```
patch('faces',Tri,'vertices',V,'facecolor', 
      'flat','edgecolor','none','facealpha',1)
```

Comment: You probably want to convert the polygons to triangles, and then use [`plot_tri_surf`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#tri-surface-plots).

Answer (score 39):

I'm not exactly sure what matlab does, but you can draw a polygon using [`matplotlib.patches.Polygon`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html?highlight=patches.polygon#matplotlib.patches.Polygon). Adapted from an [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/patch_collection.html) in the docs:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
patches = []
num_polygons = 5
num_sides = 5

for i in range(num_polygons):
    polygon = Polygon(np.random.rand(num_sides ,2), True)
    patches.append(polygon)

p = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet, alpha=0.4)

colors = 100*np.random.rand(len(patches))
p.set_array(np.array(colors))

ax.add_collection(p)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725201/set-polygon-colors-matplotlib   for improved color control